# Not possible using NHibernate?

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, sql-server-2008-r2

I am new learner to NHibernate. I am trying out samples with MSSQL database. We all know query using MSSQL is different from MYSQL database. If i need to use this sample for MYSQL, do i need to change anything other than configuration settings? Also i need to know is there anything that is not possible because of NHibernate?

Comment: did you map your relational model with your object model?

Comment: Well as about:
a) configuration see http://www.dotnetguy.co.uk/post/2010/02/14/configuring-nhibernate-to-use-mysql-ndash-and-the-small-runtime-gotcha/
b) everything is possible with nhibernate :)

Answer (score 0):

**There are multiple ways of configuring NHibernate.**
What you need to set is called:

The **dialect** is responsible for converting IQueryable, ICriteria or so called HQL (hibernate query language) to the SQL of the corresponding database.

But if you want to have this general, you **must pay attention to the ID** (in some cases even use locking). SQL has so called auto-identity, while Oracle works with sequencers. But NHibernate has it's own ways of generating identity.

**I would advise you to:**

- use latest NHibernate (not older than 3.3.x.x)
- try out fluent nhibernate mapping
- eventually find some example on nhibernate + fluent + unity/structure map (DI framework) - mostly you find something related to DDD projects